# Android Studio show "Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner' "

Tags: android

I have updated my app from gradle 2.13 to 4.1 and Android studio version 2.1.2 to 3.0.0, but when build app, app cannot run and show error : **Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner'**

While updating gradle and android stuido version, i also change output APK file name in gradle:

older :

```
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                def file = output.outputFile
                output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
            }
        }
```

newest:

```
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                def file = output.outputFile
                output.outputFileName = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
            }
        }
```

This changing is root cause for this error ? What should i do ?

Comment: SherlockSpinner is a dependency, check your `build.gradle` file. It might not be present there. And pls post your LogCat

Comment: This here : org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':libs:com_actionbarsherlock:processDebugResources'
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Caused by: com.android.builder.symbols.ResourceValuesXmlParseException: Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner'

Comment: that's not enough and is that dependency present inside your grade file?

Comment: In gradle file, there isn't SherlockSpinner in it

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency inside your `build.gradle` file

```
ependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.sherlockshi.widget:sherlockspinner:1.0.2'
}
```

The error was right there, your project was missing the above dependency, thus failed to build successfuly. You might have imported that class in your java file

Comment: I have just added your code in my gradle but this error is still happen, i think i'll comeback gradle 2.13 instead of gradle 4.1.